# Torus minus disk does not retract

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I'd like to show the following (intuitively clear) fact:

Given a torus $T^2$ and an embedded disk $D\subset T^2$ (put a disk in the middle of the square whose edges we identify to get the torus), consider $X=T^2\setminus int(D)$.

**Claim**: X does not retract to $\partial D\subset X$

What I tried: If there was such a retraction, we'd get in homology: $H_i(\partial D)\rightarrow H_i(X)\rightarrow H_i(\partial D)$. For i=1, this comes down to $\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow H_i(X)\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$. The first map is induced by inclusion, the second by our retraction, so the composition is homotopic to the identity, so it induces an isomorphism. That means I have to compute the first homology group of X, which is where I'm stuck formally.

Is what I've done so far okay (or is there a better way?) and how do I finish the proof?

Comment: $X$ can be retracted to the wedge of two circles instead, check the funny gif: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/ba/Inside-out_torus_%28animated%2C_small%29.gif

Comment: Does anyone know how to prove this using just homotopy theory arguments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint 1**: Removing the disc means you can strong deformation retract $X$ to the edges of the square, so you can calculate the homology of just the 1-skeleton.

**Hint 2**: You'll need to compute more than just the first homology group of $X$.  To complete the proof you'll need to use information about the map of homology groups induced by the inclusion $\partial D \rightarrow X$.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. First: I didn't downvote. Second: Okay, so the homology of X is Z in degree 0, Z^2 in degree 1 and 0 else. The inclusion yields an isomorphism in homology, which would be an isomorphism Z->Z^2, which is my contradiction. Correct?

Comment: @Paul The inclusion doesn't yield an isomorphism in homology, the inclusion composed with a retract does.  But the mere existence of a composition $\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}$ being the identity doesn't give a contradiction by itself, hence my second hint:  You'll need to calculate what that first map actually is.

Comment: Yeah i see it now - we're not talking about deformation retracts, just retracts... I don't see how to compute the inclusion's induced map concretely..

Comment: @Paul Think again about the deformation retract from $X$ to the square.  If you start with a loop that starts by going once around the removed disc, where does it end up at the end of the retract?  What homology element does that correspond to?

Comment: the loop is going to go once along every edge of the square. Because of the orientation of these edges, the image of the generator of $H_1(\partial D)$ is (0,0), so that the map $i_*$ is just 0..

Comment: @Paul That's correct.  So if $r$ is a retraction to $\partial D$, what can $r_*$ be in order to make the composition an isomorphism?

Comment: then $r_*$ has to send (0,0) to 1, which is absurd.